# Profile high CPU in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I have a node application. When run locally, (same node version) it works quite well, no CPU usage or anything strange.

When I run the same application within a docker container node:alpine, same version, the CPU for the container runs at 100%.

If I run the node app in debug mode within this container, and connect Chrome and profile it, there doesn't seem to be anything causing an issue - the profiler reveals that 99% of the work is in 'program' which seems to indicate the node process itself.

There aren't any other processes running in the container.  And Chrome doesn't reveal any obvious javascript issues in node.

What else can it be?

Comment: Perhaps it's node.js itself. Are you running locally with Alpine as well? If you're running locally on say, Ubuntu, try to repeat the test with Ubuntu docker.

Comment: @simbolo did you manage to resolve this issue somehow?

Comment: @simbolo How did you manage to resole this issue ?